# assign one of the cut images to a sprite renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite-sheet

**I want to assign image to a sprite renderer component**

but its not single image , its one from the cut images using sprite editor

check this image to get it : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ6b5.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Resources.LoadAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html) to get an array of sprites from the single sliced sprite.

Partial example

```
Sprite[] allSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("mySprite");  
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = allSprites[0];
```